# Conditional formula referring to preview row in DF not working

Tags: r

trying these two methods to solve a problem... but they doesn't work.

Column 3 should continue to be "1" according to the final condition after column 1 changes to 0 from 1.

```
Method 1:

a <- as.data.frame(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
b <- as.data.frame(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
df <- cbind(a,b)
df[1,3] <- 0



df[-1,3] <- ifelse(df[-1,1] == 1 & df[-1,2] == 0, 1, ifelse(df[-1,1] == 1 & 
df[-1,2] == 1, 0, df[sum(!is.na(df[,3])),3]))
```

---

Method 2:

```
a <- as.data.frame(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
b <- as.data.frame(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
df <- cbind(a,b)
df[1,3] <- 0


ndates <- as.numeric(length(df[,1]))

x <- 1

while (ndates > x - 1){

  df[-1,3] <- ifelse(df[-1,1] == 1 & df[-1,2] == 0, 1, ifelse(df[-1,1] == 1 
& df[-1,2] == 1, 0, df[sum(!is.na(df[,3])),3])) 

  x <- x + 1
}
```

Any help would be appreciated... seems like I'm missing something that is probably quite basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated answer:

Okay with a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish here's a for loop version that should be right. Let me know if I'm still missing what your intention is.

```
df[-1,3] <- ifelse(df[-1,1] == 1 & df[-1,2] == 0, 1, ifelse(df[-1,1] == 1 & 
                                                              df[-1,2] == 1, 0, df[sum(!is.na(df[,3])),3]))
a <- as.data.frame(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
b <- as.data.frame(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
df <- cbind(a,b)
df[1,3] <- 0


for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  df[i,3] <- ifelse(df[i,1] == 1 & df[i,2] == 0, 1, 
                    ifelse(df[i,1] == 1 & df[i,2] == 1, 0, df[i-1,3]))
}
```

This code loops once through each row and updates based on the rules you gave ([1,0] = 1, [1,1] = 0, otherwise previous row). And this is the resulting output:

```
> df
   c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) V3
1                                      0                                     0  0
2                                      0                                     0  0
3                                      0                                     0  0
4                                      1                                     0  1
5                                      1                                     0  1
6                                      1                                     0  1
7                                      1                                     0  1
8                                      1                                     0  1
9                                      0                                     0  1
10                                     0                                     0  1
11                                     0                                     0  1
12                                     0                                     0  1
>
```

## Initial answer:

It might be helpful if you could clarify what you're trying to accomplish. I worked through your first method and it seems to give the expected results. This is my understanding in pseudocode:

```
if C1,C2 == [1,0]:
  set C3 to 1
else:
  if C1,C2 == [1,1]:
    set C3 to 0
  else:
    set C3 to the val in col=3,row=number of non NA vals in col3
```

Since you have 1 non-NA then the final statement evaluates to cell [1,3] which is 0 so it sets all the [1,0] cases to 1 and 0 otherwise.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `df[sum(!is.na(df[,3])),3]))`? This might be a case of a logic error, but it's hard to tell without understanding what you're hoping the outcome will be.

Comment: If the first/second ifelse conditions are not met ... the result = the result of the immediately previous row.

Comment: I see. The problem with this first approach then is that that behaviour would require an iterative approach. `df[sum(!is.na(df[,3])),3]))` is only evaluated once in this approach and isn't able to dynamically get the previous results. I see your second method is loop based, I'll take a look at that one and see if I can spot the error.

Comment: @dwdionis I've gone ahead and updated the answer, let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Caio, your techniques are strong. I was able to use what you provided, with slights modifications, to complete my desired task. This is the first time I have implemented a "for" loop in practice (I have only used "while" loops before). Thanks!

Comment: So glad it helped! As for while vs for loops, what they'll tell you in any CS class is to use for loops when it'll run for a set number of iterations and while when you want it to loop indefinitely. Best of luck :)